# How many stretchable sections can 9-patch image actually have in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, layer, nine-patch

I’m trying to make an app which would display a sound signal on a ‘grid-like’ background. I’m using a transparent SurfaceView for the signal and an ImageView behind it. I’d like to make, say, 10x6 grid using a 9-patch image. Developer documentation says [you can have as many stretchable sections as you want: their relative size stays the same](http://apiminer.org/doc/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). Sounds really good for a simple grid.

It’s possible to create a 9-patch PNG with 4 vertical and 6 horizontal stretchable sections (4x6) or 6x4 sections or even 2x10 stretchable sections. The problem starts if you want to get more than 24 stretchable areas in any combination. Android just doesn't get this 9-patch image in run-time. Interestingly enough, Android Studio and draw9patch editor both display the image just fine.

What am I doing wrong? May be there is a better, more elegant way to get a simple grid?

Here is the layout file:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/surface_bg"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/surface_background4x7" 
     android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
     <!-- this code doesn't work as well:
     android:background="@drawable/surface_background4x7" -->
```

Comment: Just got a downvote, would love to get some feedback - why? I spent a few days trying to find an answer and a solution. I think others can benefit if we solve it.

Comment: Attaching the set of 9-patch images I used for testing: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37693863/nine-patch-images-4-testing.zip

Comment: why an ImageView? use simple View with custom background Drawable

Comment: @pskink yep I tried simple View too. 9-patch PNGs with multiple stretchable areas don't work anyway.

Comment: no,  no 9 patch,  use custom Drawable, for example you can use ShapeDrawable with a custom Shape: class CustomShape extends Shape { ...

Comment: `Sounds really good for a simple grid.` No, **it doesn't**. Better use a `GridView`, instead

Comment: a GridView just for making a grid lines? you are kidding,  aren't you?

Comment: Well, the biggest advantage of 9-patch "grid" is it doesn't require coding. Literally, you can make axis, ticks and marks (unlike gridview), etc. - everything would be perfectly stretchable. Yep, there are many ways to do the same but all other ways require some coding, that's the problem. Please take me right - I don't dislike coding, I'm just trying to avoid it if possible.

It turns out there are some limitations in 9-patches, unfortunately.